# How to override the migrations of a third-party django package

Tags: python, django

All the previous answers I came across are not clear or old.

I have a third-party package installed and migrations ran.

Problem is the third-party package uses an Interger field to reference users(based on the assumption that the app is using the default django user), but in my case I am using a uuid for user IDs

[package models.py](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/blob/dev/jet/dashboard/models.py)

```
class UserDashboardModule(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Title'), max_length=255)
    user = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('user'))
    column = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('column'))
    order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('order'))
    collapsed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('collapsed'), default=False)
    ...

 # Migrations of third-party package
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserDashboardModule',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, serialize=False, auto_created=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=255)),
                ('module', models.CharField(verbose_name='module', max_length=255)),
                ('app_label', models.CharField(verbose_name='application name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)),
                ('user', models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='user')),
            ]
        ),
    ]
```

My user model is like this

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

this setup makes it impossible to use the third-party package and I will like to maintain my uuids on users table.

What I want to do is to somehow override this migration and turn the user field to a uuid instead of an interger field.

PS: I have tried creating an empty migration in my users app and wrote the migration but it didn't work.

Comment: First of all, I am wondering why they'd use a `PositiveIntegerField` to represent a User relation.

Comment: same here...beats me

Comment: Since the package has no option to choose Any custom models, we are stuck. But, we can clone the repository, edit the models.py and add the package along with your project.

Comment: looks like that is the way out now, I will also see if I can add that and send a PR to them thanks

Answer (score 1):

don't know this is gonna work or not , you can set id of user model as whatever this app is comfortable to work with . then make a migration file that depends on the last migration of other app then convert your model and foreign key to whatever you want it to be .

Comment: this app wants my id to be an integer, I prefer to keep using my uuids, changing the app should be easier than changing my own uuid

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with django's `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting.

For example, I needed to override the migrations in the `puput` application, for a very similar reason to yours (they hard coded the name of what should have been a swappable dependency model).

I copied all of puput's migration files to a directory in one of my own apps, in my case `app/custom_puput_migrations` and edited them as I saw fit.

Then in `settings` I put:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'puput': 'app.custom_puput_migrations')
```

Then I recreated my database from scratch and away it went.

The downside of this is that you have to maintain those migrations; each time you upgrade the third party app version, you need to check for and copy across any migrations they may have made.